# implementing UIWebView withs swift has error

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am working on an application which I need to implement a UIWebView. I am following this tutorial, https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/04/creating-simple-browser-with-uiwebview.html
my codes are here

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIWebViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var viewWeb: UIWebView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let webUrl : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/")!
    let webRequest : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: webUrl as URL) //it has error
    viewWeb.loadRequest(webRequest as URLRequest)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }


 }
```

the problem is in the line

```
    let webRequest : NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: webUrl as URL)
```

it has this error `'init(URL:)' has been renamed to 'init(url:)'` and there is no suggestion how to fix it. does any one have any idea how to fix it?

Appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: Try my answer. it will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
    let webUrl : URL = URL(string: "https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/")!
    let webRequest : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: webUrl)
    viewWeb.loadRequest(webRequest as URLRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
viewWeb.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/")!))
```